# excel vba auto log in to hdfc bank and downloading the bank statement

Tags: vba, excel

we are trying to create a auto login to https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/
but failed to pass the values to the text box

we tried with the code below but could not login if any body please suggest what mistake I am doing it will be of great help to me.

```
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim oBrowser As InternetExplorer
Dim oHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim sURL As String
sURL = "https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/"
Set oBrowser = New InternetExplorer

oBrowser.Silent = True
oBrowser.navigate sURL
oBrowser.Visible = True

Do 'Wait till the Browser is loaded...........................
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLdoc = oBrowser.document

Sleep 2000

HTMLdoc.all("fldLoginUserId") = "45095398"
HTMLdoc.all("arcotsubmit").Click

Do 'Wait till the Browser is loaded...........................
Loop Until oBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
```

Comment: That page has a bunch of nested framesets which you'll need to sort out in order to solve this. Use the Developer tools in your browser to examine the structure of the page.  I tried view source, but got a popup "Mouse right click disabled". Classy ;-p

Comment: Thanks we tried but could find the html codes are as follows <input type="text" name="fldLoginUserId" maxlength="10" size="10" onkeypress="return fSubmit(event);" value="" class="input_password">

Answer (score 0):

The page `https://netbanking.hdfcbank.com/netbanking/` is a mixture of framesets. Even the login page is included in a frameset.

```
<FRAME marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" NAME="login_page" SRC="RSLogin.html" NORESIZE="true" scrolling="yes"/>
```

Even if you can get the `document` for the login page, note that the login page is written in javascript. The Customer ID, IPIN and Buttons are populated using the javascript

```
document.write('<input type="text" name="fldLoginUserId" maxlength="10" size="10" onkeypress = "return fSubmit(event);" value="" class="input_password"/>');
document.write('<input type="password" name="fldPassword" size="10" onfocus = "javascript:setKeyboardFocus(\'frmLogin\',\'fldPassword\');" value="" />');
```

Now I am not sure from here how you will be able to enter your information in these textboxes and then login.